# Mostrar datos de un array que contiene 2 tablas con diferentes estructuras php,mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

Quizás no se entienda el titulo, pero la idea es la siguiente:

Tengo 2 tablas, con estructuras diferentes, y deseo mostrar los datos con `FOREACH` de `php`.

ejem:

MYSQL:

---

TAB1:

id, img, contenido

---

TAB2:

id_b, img_b, contenido_b, caracteriticas_b

---

array_1 = tab1

array_2 = tab2

---

Comentarles que los array se guardan en una session:
Consigo mostrar los datos de la `tab1` pero no de la `tab2`, pero cuando quiero mostrar ambos me sale error.

```
 <?
php foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as array_1  => $tab1){
?>
```

---

Publicación Editada como respuesta:

David Gracias por responder. Comparto el código de la SESSION CARRITO, mientras te comento.. tengo 2 tablas en mysql, y con un boton almeceno en la session carrito los datos, ya sea de la primera tabla o la segunda, cada vez que le doy click se agrega el producto seleccionado, y al ingresar a carrito.php deben aparecer los datos que he seleccionado y fueron almacenados en mi session carrito. Uso el foreach para mostrar los datos en pantalla desde mysql, ya sean la imagenes y los nombres, logré que muestre uno de cada uno, osea de forma independiente pero cuando quiero que me muestre los datos de la tabla 1 q es tablaacces y de la tabla 2 que es dbtablaproducto, lo llamo con foreach y sí me muestra los datos de cada uno pero me sale error error ya que no reconoce algunasvariables, ya que en sí hago 2 foreach:

ANTES:

// foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice => $tabla1){

// foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice => $tabla2){

AHORA

// foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice => $carrito)

```
 <tr align="center"><td> <div><img src=img/productos/<?php echo $carrito ['IMG']; ?> style='width: 50px; height: 41px'></div><?php echo $carrito['NOMBRE']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['CANTIDAD']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['PRECIO']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['PRECIO']*$carrito['CANTIDAD'];?></td><td>
```

// foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice => $carrito)

```
 <tr align="center"><td> <div><img src=img/accesorios/<?php echo $carrito ['IMG_ACCS']; ?> style='width: 50px; height: 41px'></div><?php echo $carrito['NOMBRE_ACCS']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['CANTIDAD_ACCS']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['PRECIO_ACCS']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['PRECIO_ACCS']*$carrito['CANTIDAD_ACCS'];?></td><td>
```

Si te das cuenta ahí, solo uso una variable $carrito como me recomendaste, pero, tengo 2 tablas distintas, donde en la SESSION CARRITO me encargo de darle unos valores a cada uno.

[image: Esta en la imagen, aquí me está mostrando los datos de cada uno como quiero, uno es de la tabla: tablaacces y el otro es de la tabla dbtablaproducto, osea son distintas, pero el unico problema es q me aparece ese mensaje de error.]

//En la imagen anterior, me está mostrando los datos de cada uno como quiero, uno es de la tabla: tablaacces y el otro es de la tabla dbtablaproducto, osea son distintas, pero el unico problema es q me aparece ese mensaje de error.

Aquí te comparto el codigo de la SESSION CARRITO:

https://codepen.io/Paulneitor/pen/oVodVV

En ese código encontrarás lo siguiente:

if(isset($_POST['btn_action_accs'])) {

- Con esto ejecuto todo el código que sigue si se le da click al boton, dentro de este tengo un formulario q está oculto y encriptado, dicho formulario contiene los datos de mi tabla --> tablaacces q está en MYSQL

if(isset($_POST['btn_action'])) {

-- En este ejecuto todo el código que sigue si se le da click al boton, también se envía los datos de la otra tabla --> dbtablaproducto q está en MYSQL

// Ahora quizás me recomiendes hacer una tabla nada mas, pero el detalle es que las dos tablas contienen distintas estructuras y diferentes datos, aparte uso dbtablaproducto para mostrar en una paginas con FOREACH los datos que esta contien y en otra página distinta uso los datos de la otra tabla --> tablaacces, por ello es q estoy tratando de ver la forma de cómo podría dar una solución a este problemita q me generé. Saludos

//// Quizás preguntes por qué tengo dos FOREACH iguales, la verdad que recién me doy cuenta al escribirte, lo que hice ahora solo usar un FOREACH y unirlo a ver si funcionaba:

// foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice => $carrito)

```
 <tr align="center"><td> <div><img src=img/accesorios/<?php echo $carrito ['IMG_ACCS']; ?> style='width: 50px; height: 41px'></div><?php echo $carrito['NOMBRE_ACCS']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['CANTIDAD_ACCS']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['PRECIO_ACCS']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['PRECIO_ACCS']*$carrito['CANTIDAD_ACCS'];?></td><td>
```

```
 <tr align="center"><td> <div><img src=img/productos/<?php echo $carrito ['IMG']; ?> style='width: 50px; height: 41px'></div><?php echo $carrito['NOMBRE']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['CANTIDAD']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['PRECIO']?></td><td><?php echo $carrito['PRECIO']*$carrito['CANTIDAD'];?></td><td>
```

-Al hacer ello es obvio que ahorro líneas, pero el problema persiste porq tiene variables distintas:

tablaacces:

//  echo $carrito ['IMG_ACCS'];   ->distinto

dbtablaproducto:
// echo $carrito ['IMG']; -> distinto

Pero estas variables deben ser así porq en SESSIONCARRITO, el cod que te pasé por codepen, declaro estás variables por independiente.

Te muestro la imagen actual después de colocar solo un FOREACH:

el detalle el q sí, me muestra los datos que quiero pero me sale esos mensajes de error :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenos dias Paul. Échale un ojo a [ask] y a [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte correctamente con tu problema. Adjuntanos algo de código de lo que tienes hecho, la consulta que estás utilizando, etc. Para poder darte una guía adecuada. Un saludo y bienvenido.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas, creo que te estás liando con el foreach. Te paso este código y ya me confirmas si se entiende:

```
<?php
    foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice=>$carrito){
        echo 'En la primera vuelta $carrito será tab1 y en la segunda tab2';
        print_r($carrito);
    }
?>
```

Si aún no se ve, envíame el contenido de $_SESSION['CARRITO'] y le damos una vuelta más

Comment: Hola David,  gracias, pero aún no funciona, ahora te respondo con más detalle.

Comment: Esto ya es otra cosa, así se pregunta... :) Si no se me adelanta nadie, mañana te lo miro, que hoy ya se me ha hecho muy tarde. Un saludo

Comment: Hola David, de acuerdo y gracias de todas maneras :)

Comment: Vale, tenemos que simplificar esto un poco que, al menos a mí, se me hace bola. Por los mensaje de error que veo en los pantallazos hay elementos del array que no has inicializado y, por otra parte, hablas de tablas en MySQL, pero rellenas los arrays manualmente. En definitiva, que me pierdo un poco entre tanto código. ¿Sería posible que reproducieras este error en un ejemplo con el menor número de líneas de código posible? Me refiero a un ejemplo de lo que falla para poder arreglarlo y lo lleves después tu programa.

Comment: Hola David, comentarte que encontré una alternativa de solución, no es exactamente lo q estaba buscando pero lo que hice es crear una sola tabla y en la session carrito le coloco las mismas variable de producto y accesorios, el resultado es que ya me aparece las imagenes y el detalle, me almacena la session y no sale error, Saludos :)

Comment: Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto. Ya que no hemos resuelto nada por aquí, lo suyo sería eliminar la pregunta para no dejarla inconclusa. Saludos.